# New-AzServiceBusRule cmdlet randomly failing with "already exists" error

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-powershell, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am trying to automate the infrastructure of my application. As part of that, I am creating Service Bus related resources (Namespace, Topics, Subscriptions) only if they do not exist. My subscriptions will only have 1 rule. So every time the script runs, it will delete all existing rules and create this rule from scratch.

Here's the pseudo code I am writing:

```
$topic = Get-AzServiceBusTopic -Name $TopicName -NamespaceName $NamespaceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($null -eq $topic -or $notPresent)
{
    $topic = New-AzServiceBusTopic -Name TopicName -NamespaceName NamespaceName -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction Stop
}
$subscription = Get-AzServiceBusSubscription -Name $SubscriptionName -TopicName $TopicName -NamespaceName $NamespaceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorVariable notPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($null -eq $subscription -or $notPresent)
{
    $subscription = New-AzServiceBusSubscription -Name SubscriptionName -TopicName TopicName -NamespaceName NamespaceName -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction Stop
}
# forcefully delete existing rules
Get-AzServiceBusRule -SubscriptionName SubscriptionName -TopicName TopicName -NamespaceName NamespaceName -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName | Remove-AzServiceBusRule
# create rule
$rule = New-AzServiceBusRule -Name "`$Default"  -SubscriptionName SubscriptionName -TopicName TopicName -NamespaceName NamespaceName -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName -FilterType SqlFilter -SqlExpression SqlFilterExpression -ErrorAction Stop
```

Randomly I am seeing `New-AzServiceBusRule` Cmdlet call fails with the following error:

> The messaging entity
> 'namespacename:Topic:topicname|subscriptionname|$Default'
> already exists. To know more visit
> | https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.  TrackingId:823eeae9-8776-46e7-90de-5ec305e14bb5_B26,
> SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker,
> | Timestamp:2023-05-13T10:33:37

According to the documentation of [`New-AzServiceBusRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/new-azservicebusrule?view=azps-9.7.1), the cmdlet either creates a new rule and updates an existing rule. If that is the case, then why am I getting the resource exists exception.

I even tried waiting for a second before deleting all existing rules and creating the new rule but that did not help either.

Interesting thing is that it happens randomly. For some of the Subscriptions and Rules, the code works just fine and then randomly for one odd Subscription, it would fail. At times, it will not fail at all!

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I am not receiving any such error for various rules or examples as below: https://i.imgur.com/bCHnSFH.png,   https://i.imgur.com/RQE1ggO.png

Comment: @RithwikBojja - Thank you for looking into this. I really appreciate it. As I mentioned, it happens very randomly. Can you try the same with `$Default` rule?

Comment: Yeah give me  a minute'

Answer (score 1):

> The messaging entity 'namespacename:Topic:topicname|subscriptionname|$Default' already exists.

This error shouldn't come, as per [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/new-azservicebusrule?view=azps-9.7.1) and my analysis below is clearly says that this error will not come :
With `$Deafult`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

One can clearly see I hadn't received any error for different rules too that are already existing with me.

If whenever I see these errors in other commands i integrate below commands into my script:

```
$emo=Get-AzServiceBusRule -SubscriptionName "rithwik" -TopicName "rithwik" -NamespaceName "rithwik1" -ResourceGroupName "rgname"
foreach ($e in $emo.Name)
{
    Remove-AzServiceBusRule -SubscriptionName "rithwik" -TopicName "rithwik" -NamespaceName "rithwik1" -ResourceGroupName "rg name" -Name $e
}
$rule = New-AzServiceBusRule -Name "vammo"  -SubscriptionName "rithwik" -TopicName "rithwik" -NamespaceName "rithwik1" -ResourceGroupName "rgname" -FilterType SqlFilter -SqlExpression '1=1' -ErrorAction Stop
```

Even with $default not getting any error :

[image]

If the issue still persists , I would suggest you to raise a support request.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will wait to hear someone from Service Bus team to look into this otherwise I will raise a support ticket as suggested by you.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a ticket to Azure support about this topic some months ago and they just told me they expect a fix to be fully deployed by the end of next week.